# Opening hyperlink from javafx

Tags: javafx-2

Here scenario is i just want to open the hyperlink which will navigate to help document html pages of my javafx application and these html pages are placed in the folder where my applicatons jar is present. I tried to use webview and webengine to load it but its not working  and i am also not getting any exception for it.Kindly help, below is my code for the same:

```
@FXML
    private void handleHelpLink(ActionEvent event) {

        String driveName = LoginView.runTimeDriveName();
        String url = driveName + "/html/Pheonix Setup.html";
        webEngine.load(url);

    }
```

NOTE: i am using JAVAFX 2.1

UPDATED CODE:

```
public class HelpDoc extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        String driveName = LoginView.runTimeDriveName();
        final String url = driveName + "/html/Pheonix Setup.html";
        System.out.println("URL="+url);
        engine.load(url);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the WebView to your Scene/Stage? You can have a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) for a simple example.

Comment: I have added the webview in scene but still its not working.It will be ok for me if we can directly open that html page in the systems default browser.Can we do this?

Comment: you should be more specific and define "is not working". If you want good answers, you should show a complete (but simple) example that recreates your problem: create the webview/webengine, add it to a scene / stage, load a url. Are you sure your `handleHelpLink` method is called? Are you sure your url is valid? etc.

Comment: URL is valid and handleHelpLink in getting called . Here i have created new class and opening new stage from it and trying to open that html page on that stage.Please find the code of my class.Its not displaying anything on it.

Comment: try with `final String url = "http://www.google.com";` and see if it works (it does for me). Note that you need the `http` part, with `url = "www.google.com"` the page does not open.

Comment: see here the html page i want to invoke is placed on my local drive i just want to give path of these pages.When url is like "D:/Workspace_NetBeans/Phoenix/dist/html/Pheonix Setup.html" its not working after changing it to "http://D:/Workspace_NetBeans/Phoenix/dist/html/Pheonix Setup.html" still its not working .Any guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load a local html file in a WebView, you need to provide a valid URL:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/file.html");
engine.load(path.toUri().toURL().toString());
```

using Java 7. If you use Java 6:

```
File f = new File("C:\\file.html");
engine.load(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
```